# Cannot simulate click on jest test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs

I'm learning some **react + testing with jest**, I have a component which has **three numeric inputs and a button**. It's a simple calculator with the multiply operation only.

Don't worry about the rest of the code, I'm just trying to simulate the click that performs the operation *(in this case it will call a mocked function as shown in the test)*

**This is the test**

```
function setup() {
    const component = shallow(<Multiplier />);

    return {
       component: component,
       button: component.find('#multiplyButton')
    }
}

describe('Given a Multiplier instantiated', () => {
   it('The button perform operation should invoke the click method', () => {
       const { button } = setup();
       const handleClick = jest.fn();
       button.onclick = handleClick;
       button.simulate('onClick');
       expect(handleClick).toBeCalled();
   });
});
```

I think the **button.onclick** assignment is wrong, I tried with prototype and ecma6 Object.assign but it was the same result, the test fails.

I mocked the onclick button with jest.fn(), once the button is pressed it should call this method, but it's always telling me:

**Given a Multiplier instantiated › The button perform operation should invoke the click method
expect(jest.fn()).toBeCalled()**

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `button` is `ShallowWrapper` and you cant set `onclick` like there. You should pass mock function to `onClick` button prop. And I prefer to test only the public API of the component, because a private method is an implementation detail that should be hidden to the users of the component.

```
// Your component
const MyButton = ({ label, onClick }) => (
  <button type='button' onClick={onClick}>{label}</button>
)

// Your test
describe('<MyButton/>', () => {
  test('should call onClick callback', () => {
    const onClick = jest.fn();
    const wrapper = shallow(<MyButton onClick={onClick}/>);
    wrapper.simulate('click');
    expect(onClick).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```